# Retrieving profile picture with parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I set up a profile picture for users following the code [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/update-table-user-with-a-profile-image), but I can't seem to retrieve the picture. The code I tried is below please help me out can't seem to figure this out:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"profilePic" block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(object);
        }
        else{
           // Error stuff 
        }
}];
```

Comment: Did you check if error is nil? I recommend you to put `NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);` in the else block.

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood the purpose of `getObjectInBackgroundWithId:block:` ... the first parameter is meant to be the ID of the object you want to get. Inside the block you can then query for properties of the object you've gotten.

e.g. if you want the current user:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[PFUser currentUser].objectId block:^(PFObject *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        PFFile *profilePic = user[@"profilePic"];
        [profilePic getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            }
        }];
    }
    else{
       // Error stuff 
    }
}];
```